# Best RoR aptana radRails tutorial for the total beginner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I'm an application developer going web.

After deciding to dump google-apps I'm now starting with Aptana's Rad Rails.

Is there a simple tutorial which will take me through a sample project like "stock quote project" or such for Ruby? which is the best one?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Best sources of information I've found in getting started are

1. The Rails Guides:  [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) - the getting started will give a quick start/introduction on how to get started.  This was the most concise and readable introduction.
2. [Agile web development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) - covers building an application and also some more in depth information on the Rails framework.
3. [Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) is an invaluable guide to Ruby and it's easy to read; nicely formatted with easy examples, a clear concise table of contents which lets you find things quickly and easily.  You may need this if you require understanding some code examples since Rails is of course simply written in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The best guide for getting started in Rails is the [Official Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should just follow any Rails documentation of your choice, such as the [official guides site](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html).

RadRails is an IDE designed for Ruby & Rails which will make some things like generating models, etc. easier by providing a GUI frontend for such things. Otherwise, the workflow is exactly the same as usual.